# Something wrong with isset($_POST)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make registration form, but there is some problem, I can't get where it is.

Errors:
**Notice**: Undefined index: username in ...
**Notice**: Undefined index: password in ...

```
<form method="POST">
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = md5($_POST['password']);

                if(empty($username) or empty($password)) {
                    echo "<p>Fields are empty!</p>";
                } else {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$username', '$password', '2', '')");
                    echo "<p>Registration successful!</p>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        <p><label for="username">Username: </label><input type="text" id="username" /></p>
        <p><label for="password">Password: </label><input type="password" id="password" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up">
    </form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Simple: Your form elements are not named. Plus, don't use MD5, it's old and considered broken.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: Comment(s) fall onto deaf ears, *once again*. Good luck with that; you might need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the name for your inputs:

```
<label for="username">Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
<label for="password">Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
```

That should fix the problem!

Comment: Yes, I forgot to set names. Thanks!

Comment: well really @Fred -ii-  deserves the points, but he's to cool to need them

Comment: I was posting the answer while I guess Fred posted. But it was a simple fix so I am sure many others knew it too.